# Access Sony Xperia S' internal storage without power

Tags: internal-storage, sony-xperia

I had some struggles with my phone over the last few months, but now the power button isn't working anymore (button fell off and also this "[power-button-mechanism](http://www.repairsuniverse.com/sony-xperia-s-lt26i-power-button-flex-cable-replacement.html)" is broken.), I can't switch it on anymore and I would need to get some files from the device's internal storage. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a reasonably priced replacement.

There is a similar question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45816/how-to-access-samsung-galaxy-s2-storage-while-phone-is-off?newreg=4709aa18a44e4ecbbb4d2ef536e4f391) regarding Samsung Galaxy S2, but different to this, my phone is way out of warranty and I already disassembled it to the mainboard (should be working still as the red LED flashes and my PC recognizes an unknown device when connected via USB)

[image: mainboard]

I guess I have three possibilities:

- Replace power module: as mentioned above, I couldn't find a replacement for good value.
- "Repair" power module: it seems that the power button (when pressed) only connects two conductors, but the flex band is torn, I tried to kind of reconnect them, but I don't really have the equipment for this tiny stuff.
- Access internal storage directly (maybe via [JTAG](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37019/what-is-jtag-in-regards-to-android)): it's also mentioned in the Galaxy S2 post from above:

  > ... all you could do to access its storage is using some JTAG like device to get physically access...

I don't really know anything about that, does anybody have experience with that? And as I have disassembled the phone already, I'm quite interested in how latter approach would work.